# Authorize my app to create Paypal adaptive payment refunds

Tags: paypal, paypal-adaptive-payments, paypal-rest-sdk

From Paypal [doc](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/adaptive-payments/Refund_API_Operation/)

> A receiver can grant you third-party access to make a refund by
>   logging in to PayPal, choosing API Access on the Profile page, then
>   clicking the link to Grant API permission and selecting Refund after
>   clicking Configure a custom API authorization.

Hope dies last, there a way to bypass this step, maybe mixing REST API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Permissions API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/permissions-service/integration-guide/PermissionsAbout/) and tie it directly into your app.